# How to used url link to load an object

Tags: javascript

please help me on this im using a local path to load object image "textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg" but i need to upload an image to used only the url path

how can i change this local path "textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg" into url link.

```
 var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
  loader.load( 'textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function ( image ) {

  texture.image = image;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;

  } );
```

Comment: Do you simply need to append the address of the current page to that path?

Comment: I meant are you trying to turn the relative path into an absolute path? If you have `textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg` do you want to turn it into something like `http://www.exapleurl.com/path/to/file/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg`? I'm just trying to understand your question. You worded it in a very confusing way.

Comment: yes i need to change the "textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg" in to link "http://www.exapleurl.com/path/to/file/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg".